# Using SET statement in a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my scenario. I have a stored procedure that has a select query.

```
Select M ,X , Y, dbo.function(parameters) as Z 
from SomeTable 
where condition1 
and condition2 
and Z > SomeValue
```

the Z in the where clause is the calculated value from the function.

The dbo.function returns a single value always.

I dont want to use the function in the where clause. I want to set the value to a variable and use that variable in the where clause.

How should this be done? kindly help.

Comment: Please show ur function and ur total sp

Comment: If the function is deterministic, it shouldn't matter how many times it textually appears in the query - it should just be invoked once for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like

```
DECLARE @Z TYPE_GOES_HERE = dbo.function(parameters)

Select  M ,X , Y,  @Z as Z 
from    SomeTable 
where   condition1 
and     condition2 
and     @Z > SomeValue
```

This will only work, if the parameters passed to the function is not columns from the table. If it was dependant, you coul duse a CTE. Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
    Select  M ,X , Y,  dbo.function(parameters) as Z 
    from    SomeTable 
)
SELECT  *
FROm    Vals
where   condition1 
and     condition2 
and     Z > SomeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyVar INT
SELECT  @MyVar = dbo.function(parameters)

SELECT  somethings
FROM    tables
WHERE   field = @MyVar
```

Answer (score 0):

for your requirements, u can use select inside select, steady =)

```
SELECT * FROM (
Select M ,X , Y, dbo.function(parameters) as Z 
from SomeTable 
where condition1 
and condition2 
) T1
WHERE Z > SomeValue
```